# Clean urls in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm currently testing clean url with php on my localhost server using xampp

I've got the following code for .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

The php code

```
<?php
echo $_GET['page'];
?>
```

This url works & prints the parameter ("42") : `http://localhost/folder/index.php?page=42`

When testing this url it display only the text content & all site becomes only textual : `http://localhost/folder/index.php/page/42/`

So why isn't the url responding ?

Comment: Cool story bro. So what's the question?

Comment: lol , why isn't the url responding

Comment: Your URL and your RULE are clearly different. Is your `.htaccess` on the `www` folder or on a folder called `folder` inside the `www` folder? Why are you trying to access `http://localhost/folder/index.php/page/42/` instead of `http://localhost/page/42/` or `http://localhost/folder/page/42/`?

Comment: my "index.php" file is in "folder" & this folder is in htdocs

Comment: @Prix your link works,but why is the site not loading any css styles & any images, it just displays the text ?

Comment: @user1477731 because you're using relative URL `css/my.css`, you need to use the absolute URL for css, js and images otherwise it will assume the path to it is `http://localhost/folder/page/42/css/my.css` so you need to use the absolute path like `http://localhost/css/my.css`